# Get the string after the second underscore in PHP

Tags: php, string, substr

1_0_This is string

456_1_This_is_other_string_next

1999999_12_Is-string-too

How to get: This is string, This_is_other_string_next, Is-string-too

Thanks

Comment: There was a very similar question yesterday. It also showed no code attempts. Please show what coding issue you are having.

Comment: I don't think that a code attempt is required in this case if the OP has no idea how to manipulate strings in PHP.

Comment: @asiby `substr` is tagged (not the approach I would take but could be done).

Comment: it this one string or different strings?

Comment: Different string. These are example. It came: id + number + file name

Answer (score 6):

Just an example to think about:

```
echo explode('_', '1_0_This is string', 3)[2];
echo explode('_', '1999999_12_Is-string-too', 3)[2];
```

Comment: I dont known anything after second _, maybe included many _, we can't done with explode.

Comment: thanks for help. I know explode, this is a basic function, it will not work with: 456_1_This_is_other_string_next

Comment: Oh, that is my mistake. Sorry. Your solution is elegant, many thanks :)

Comment: If one of the answers here helped you - feel free to __accept__ it.

Answer (score 3):

You can trying exploding the original string using `_` as a delimiter using `explode(string $delimiter, string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX]): array` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Than you can count the number of items in the resulting array and return something accordingly.

Example ...

```php
$string = "1_0_This is string";

$parts = explode('_', $string);

$result = "";

if (count($parts) >= 3) {
  $result = $parts[2];
}

print $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_replace with a limit

```
echo preg_replace('/[^_]+_/', '', '1999999_12_Is-string-too', 2);
```

Output

```
Is-string-too
```

The Regex is simple.  Match anything not `_` (more then one time, greedy) followed by a `_`.  Limit 2 replacements.

Using Preg Split

```
print_r(preg_split('/^([^_]+_){2}/', '456_1_This_is_other_string_next', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => This_is_other_string_next
)
```

Basically the same regex, but this one matches the first 2 times the pattern happens.  You can do the same thing with preg_replace, but it's kind of pointless there.